Is this syntax correct to auto mount a partition using fstab?
I'm new to Ubuntu so please be kind!
I am trying to get a partiton to load on start-up and understand that this should be done via fstab.
After lots of reading I thought that I needed to add the following to fstab for this to work:
/dev/sdc1/by-uuid/1212f3b3-b350-42d4-b47d-6ed9b138631d /media/Movies 
ext3 rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,user,async 0 2

But when I verify the fstab I get the following error:
[W] non-bind mount source /swap.img is a directory or regular file
/media/Movies
[W] unreachable source: /dev/sdc1/by-uuid/1212f3b3-b350-42d4-b47d-6ed9b138631d: Not a directory
[W] cannot detect on-disk filesystem type (Not a directory)

It would be appreciated if someone could tell me what I doing wrong, as I can mount the partition manually to this directory.
EDIT
Full output from etc/fstab below
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/6db6b7d4-2b61-41b7-ae02-76c82fd6d0bc / ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/DA2A-18E4 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0

Thanks in advance.


is your file system really ext3? Can you post a graphic of disks showing the UUID /dev/sdc1

Either use /dev/sdc1 (not recommended) or /dev/disk/by-uuid, alternatively you could use UUID=1212f3b3-b350-42d4-b47d-6ed9b138631d. You don't provide the fstab-line for the other warning about swap.img, so impossible to say what's wrong with it. Best is to edit your question and add full output of `cat /etc/fstab'.

Also a good idea and sometimes question can not be answered without including the version of Ubuntu being used.

UUID/1212f3b3-b350-42d4-b47d-6ed9b138631d /media/Movies
ext3 noatime 1 2 --- Should be enough.

Thanks @mook765 I've added the additional detail for the fstab.

Yes @graham its formatted ext3, is it better to be another format - I read somewhere that ext3 was the best option if it was only going to be used with Linux? Screenshot of Disks is attached as a link in the mesage.

@mr_rumpler The line for /swap.img looks ok, the warning shouldn't hurt.
